# Convert Hashtable to List of Objects

Tags: c#, list, linq, object, hashtable

How do we convert a Hashtable to a List of objects? Is it possible?

Business Object:-

```
[Serializable]
public class ColourEntry
{
    public string Id 
    {
        get { return this.id; }
        set { this.id= value; }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.name= value; }
    }
    public Hashtable Properties
    {
        get { return this.properties; }
        set { this.properties = value; }
    }
}
```

Data Contract:-

```
[DataContract(Name = "Color", Namespace = Constants.Namespace)]
public class ColorContract
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<PropertiesContract> Properties { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "Properties", Namespace = Constants.Namespace)]
public class PropertiesContract
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Business object to data contract Mapper function:-

```
public static List<ColorContract> MapContract(IList<ColourEntry> colourEntryList)
{
    var colorContract = colourEntryList.Select(x => new ColorContract()
    {
        Id = x.Id.ToDisplayString(),
        Name = x.Name,
        Properties = x.Properties
    }
    return colorContract;
 }
```

This gives me error of

> "Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Hashtable'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'"

because ColorEntry is object having properties as hashtable.

I have also tried x.Properties.ToList() but these also do not work.

Comment: Show what `ColourEntry.Properties` is. A hash-table consists of keys and values.

Comment: Where is the `HashTable` in your code? I assume it's the property `Properties` in the `ColourEntry` class which you haven't shown(!).

Comment: where you use MapContract?

Comment: `x.Properties.ToList()` probably. What have you tried?

Comment: @CodeCaster I have updated my question and the answer is marked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the `HashTable` in your code? I assume it's the property `Properties` in the `ColourEntry` class. So you want to convert that `HashTable` to `List<PropertiesContract>`.

I guess this is what you want (`hashTable.Cast<DictionaryEntry>`):

```
var colorContract = colourEntryList.Select(x => new ColorContract()
{
    Id = x.Id.ToDisplayString(),
    Name = x.Name,
    Properties = x.Properties
        .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
        .Select(kv => new PropertiesContract{ Key = kv.Key.ToString(), Value = kv.Value?.ToString() })
        .ToList()
}
return colorContract;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This resolution works with small modification 
Properties = x.Properties.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Select(kv => new PropertiesContract { Key = kv.Key.ToString(), Value = kv.Value.ToString() }).ToList()